# data grid bound with dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, drop-down-menu

How do I dynamically change the content of a data grid to select the correct data from database when the drop down list SelectedIndexChanged event happens?

To be more specific, I have a dropdown list of apple, orange and pearl.

When the dropdown list changes from apple to orange, I want the datagrid to query the database like this "select count(*) from fruit where name='orange'" and dynamically update the content.

Comment: Your description is very far from something that might be qualified as an answerable question. I would suggest you reading [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for useful tips.

Comment: Change the query based on the new selected value. Use parameters for this.

Comment: You can dynamically bind to a DataSource, but it's difficult to tell what you want to happen.  Can you provide a little more background (i.e. I have a DDL and OnSelectedIndexChanged I need x data in my datagrid) or (I have datagrid Y and when user selects option from DDL, I want x to happen to the data in the control's row) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one also make surethat your DropDownList1 have the AutoPostBack property set to true

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDatabaseDataContext mydb = new MyDatabaseDataContext();
        var x = from y in mydb.MyTable
                where y.myField == DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
                select y;
        GridView1.DataSource = x;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```